# Why can't I get 'sessionid' on the client side?

Tags: javascript, django, session, cookies, client-side-scripting

I log into django admin. When I open *firebug* JS console and try to print cookies with `document.cookie` I only get `csrftoken` cookie. But when I open Firefox preferences > Privacy > Delete cookie... then I can see `sessionid` cookie.

How to get that on client side?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot access the session cookie because it is by default set to HTTPOnly.(You can see it using Firebug(Resources->Cookies->sessionid's HTTP column is checked))

Copying from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-httponly):

> ```
> SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY
> Default: True
>
> Whether to use HTTPOnly flag on the session cookie. 
> If this is set to True, client-side JavaScript will not to 
> be able to access the session cookie.
> ```

You can set: `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False` in your settings.py if you really want to have access to it from client side code. Nevertheless it not a recommended practice.

Comment: Just a note that the reason that it's not recommended practice is that if your site is somehow susceptible to XSS, then an attacker could use this to steal session IDs. This of course isn't possible if the session ID isn't exposed to JS land.

Comment: Another note from the docs: "There’s not much excuse for leaving this off, either: if your code depends on reading session cookies from JavaScript, you’re probably doing it wrong."